# How can i improve my website response time when using https(ssl)

Tags: django, apache, performance, https

My website is on Django with Apache and mod_wsgi.

My website responsive times are around 500ms when I use http.

But when I installed ssl certificate on server for https.

My server responsive times are going up to 1300ms.

So what should do to improve my website response time when I use https(ssl).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically about https:

- Activate http2 : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html
- Use OCSP Stapling : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ocsp-stapling-on-apache-and-nginx
- Use Session resumption
- Check your cache headers (some browser may cache a little less with https)
- Avoid really slow Cipher Suites (like 3DES)